# Forking a binary tree, fork functionality issue

Tags: c, linux, tree, fork, std

Ok, So i've been looking this all over stackoverflow, and definitely googling for a good half an hour, but the answers I seem to get have barely anything to do with what I actually want to do, hopefully someone will help me on this one, heres the code:

```
int cCount = 0;

while(cCount < 2)
{
    switch(fork())
    {
    case 0:
    cCount++;
    break;

    case -1:
    printf("Failed");
    break;

    default:
    break;
    }
}

return;
```

Now for the questions that arise, this code is suppose to create a tree that has 3 levels (0,1,2),

0 being primary parent from which it starts forking

1 being 2 childs of the parent in 0

2 being 4 childs of the 2 parents in 1

Creating a symmetric tree. Essentially though I have a few questions:

1. Switch executes fork on every loop, so in theory if fork > 0, it will still be forked creating a sub child for a parent and the loop will keep going, therefore it might end up with a chain parent-parent-parent-parent, instead of 2 children per parent, then 4 for 2 etc. How does fork knows what to do?
2. Say I want to do a tree that has one more child attached to it at the last layer (level) for example, how would I start?

Do I understand fork correctly? Please explain if not, theres quite alot of tutorials around the net, but they all seem to make it way more complicated than it might be.

Cheers, thanks
And be kind to me, english is not my native tongue.

Answer (score 0):

This code will basically fork bomb, and here's why:

When the process hits the first `fork`, it'll return 0 for the child, and a positive number (the PID of the child) for the parent. Thus, the parent's instance of `cCount` will never increment, so the loop will run forever.

Comment: Nice to know i designed a DoS, always handy. In that case how to you call a fork inside a forked child. Because if you call just fork() it will fork the parent only.

Comment: What you need to do is swap some stuff around, so the `cCount++;` line is in the `default:` block, not the `case 0:` block. Also, you should add the line `cCount = 0;` to the `case 0:` block.

To keep it from looping forever, you'll need a `level` variable that starts at zero and gets incremented right after the `cCount = 0;` line I just mentioned. You can then use that variable to determine if you should keep forking.